# How to show $\cos(3\pi/2 - a) = -\sin(a)$?

Tags: trigonometry

$$\cos(3\pi/2 - a) = -\sin(a)$$

According to an answer to one of the questions in my book that's true, but come up with that? $$\cos(\pi/2 - a) = \sin(a),$$ but this is $3\pi/2$. Do you just ignore if $\pi$ is multiplied by anything or?

Comment: That's because $\cos{(x\pm y)}=\cos{x}\cos{y}\mp\sin{x}\sin{y} $

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/737353/409) may help your understanding.

Comment: Does it help to picture a diameter drawn through the unit circle?  If it crosses the circle at $(x,y)$, it should also cross at $(-x,-y)$ and the 2 radii are separated by 180 degrees.

Comment: Hmm... I think maybe I get it somewhat.

Comment: @windy401 Did the answer I provided helped? Should you approve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this picture solves it for you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hint $cos(a-b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)+\sin(a)\sin(b)$ can you get it now.