# Intuition for the identity $\sin 3x = \cos\left(3x - \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$

Tags: trigonometry

Can someone explain to me in any way why the following is true?

> $$\sin 3x = \cos\left(3x - \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$

I tried to look at the unit circle but I didn't really understand it.

Comment: Look at a right angle triangle not the unit circle.  It basically amounts to choosing an angle in the right-triangle and labelling the sides accordingly.  I will try to put a more fuller answer when I've chance but I hope it helps.  Ditch the $3x$ putting $u=3x$ for simplicity.

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/737212/how-to-remember-a-particular-class-of-trig-identities/737353#737353).

Comment: hint: $\cos\theta = \cos(-\theta)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Because](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/737212/how-to-remember-a-particular-class-of-trig-identities/737353#737353) $\sin x=\cos \left( x-\frac\pi 2\right)$

If you want another proof: Use trigonometric identity: $\cos(x-y)=\cos x \cos y+\sin x \sin y$, let $x=3x,y=\frac\pi2$

Hope it helps.

(link quoted from comment above)