# Proof of $\sin (\frac{3 \pi}{2}-A)=-\cos (A)$ geometrically

Tags: trigonometry

We already know that

$\sin (\frac{3 \pi}{2}-A)=-\cos (A)$ but is there any method to prove it geometrically?

Could someone suggest something?

Comment: Have you drawn a picture when $0 < A \le \frac\pi 2$? It's pretty suggestive.

Comment: @pjs36 Yes. But how would that take care of $\frac{3 \pi}{2}-A$ ?

Comment: See the question ["How to remember a particular class of trig identities"](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/737212/how-to-remember-a-particular-class-of-trig-identities/737353#737353).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $|A|<\pi$, and let ${\bf a}=(u,v)\in S^1$ represent the angle $A$. Then $\bar {\bf a}=(u,-v)$ represents the angle $-A$. In order to obtain the point ${\bf b}$ representing angle $B:=-A+{3\pi\over2}$ we have to rotate $\bar {\bf a}$ by ${3\pi\over2}$ counterclockwise, or what is the same thing: by ${\pi\over2}$ clockwise. Such a rotation has the effect $(x,y)\mapsto(y,-x)$ on points $(x,y)$. It follows that ${\bf b}=(-v,-u)$, so that we obtain
$$\sin\left({3\pi\over2}-A\right)=\sin B=-u=-\cos A\ ,$$
as claimed.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to your text book how the radius vector (always >0) rotates, and how trig functions change sign as  *ratios of lengths*. Or in the following net available source,

[RadiusVectorRotn](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=trig%20relation%20graphs&biw=991&bih=461&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiEipqp5ZTMAhULp5QKHSSOClUQ_AUIBigB#imgrc=sAZ9uk-M-4J4sM%3A)

Sin is $>0$ in quadrants 1,2 and $<0$ in quadrants 3,4. To remember sign of trig function in each quadrant keep in  mind: All Silver Tea Cups. Accordingly,

$$\sin (\frac{\pi}{2}-A)=+\cos (A)$$ 
$$\sin (\frac{2 \pi}{2}-A)=+\cos (A)$$ 
$$\sin (\frac{3 \pi}{2}-A)=-\cos (A)$$ 
$$\sin (\frac{4 \pi}{2}-A)=-\cos (A).$$