# Quadrant/CAST Rule Trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

I should have asked this question 6 months ago, when I learned this.

When using the quadrant diagram, how is it say for angle of 120 degrees, you can use 60 degrees to find trig ratios?

Like in this image - [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvQRG.png)

Comment: hello help please

Comment: Answers to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/737212/409) may aid your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You have

$120$ degrees$=90 +30$  or

$=\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{6}$.

we use following formulas:

$cos(a+\frac{\pi}{2})=-sin(a)$

$sin(a+\frac{\pi}{2})=cos(a)$.