# Why is $\sin(155^\circ)$ same as $\sin(25^\circ)$?

Tags: trigonometry

I am practicing for a test and i've come across this question which asks "*What is the value of $\sin(25^\circ)$ if $\sin(155^\circ) = 0.423$?*"

and I've checked on the calculator, both give same result; $0.423.$
why do they have the same value?
how would you know this without using a calculator?

Comment: More generally, $\sin(180^\circ - x)  = \sin(x)$  Can you think of the sine in terms of right triangles?

Comment: Related (possibly duplicate): ["How to remember a particular class of trig identities"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/737212/409). The titular class includes $\sin(\pi -x)= \sin x$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try drawing a circle sin is the height. You will see that at the angle 155 degrees it is the same height as 25 degrees.

[image]

Comment: Thank you :D now i see... But shouldn't one of them give -0.42 ? instead of both giving +0.42?

Comment: they are both the same height. To get -0.42  ad 180 degrees so sin(205).

Comment: I upvoted this answer. But this illustration reminds me of those images accompanying some Wikipedia articles where you can't edit them to clean up the typesetting, so you see things like $$ \begin{align} & \sin\,\alpha{=}\sin\,(\pi\text{-}\alpha) & \text{instead of} & \qquad \sin\alpha = \sin(\pi-\alpha) \\ & \cos\,(\pi\text{-}\alpha) = \text{-}\,\cos\,\alpha & \text{instead of} & \qquad \cos(\pi-\alpha) = -\cos\alpha \end{align} $$

Answer (score 1):

$$ \sin ( \pi - \alpha ) = \sin \pi \cos \alpha -\cos \pi \sin \alpha = \sin \alpha $$