# A doubt regarding proof of values of trigonometric functions at allied angles

Tags: trigonometry

There are certain identities that help us to determine the values of trigonometric functions at $\dfrac{\pi}{2}+x \text{, } \pi-x$ etc. given the values of $\sin x, \cos x$.

Now, when we prove such identities, we usually take the value of $x$ to be in the interval $\Big (0, \dfrac{\pi}{2} \Big )$. Isn't it necessary to prove the identities by taking the value of $x$ in all $4$ *quadrants* individually and then arriving at the outcome? If not, then why not?

Pardon me if this sounds silly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the basis of your proofs are from Euler's identity $e^{i \theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$ then the quadrant becomes irrelevant.

Also consider the identities $\cos \theta = \dfrac {e^{i \theta} + e^{-i \theta} } 2$ and $\sin \theta = \dfrac {e^{i \theta} - e^{-i \theta} } 2$.

Comment: The concept of complex numbers has not been introduced to me yet. In my Mathematics textbook, they have been proved using a unit circle and finding the coordinates of the points where the allied angles intersect with the unit circle. Shall I elaborate?

Comment: No, I understand the form. My answer would be: yes, I would apply a geometrical argument to all 4 quadrants. A proof that did not would probably not satisfy me if I were doing it that way. BTW not a silly question at all.

Comment: It doesn't satisfy me too! Thanks

Comment: By the way, the identities that you mention in your answer, they are related to complex numbers, right?

Comment: Yes they are -- they crop up when you try to define trig functions for complex numbers. By that stage, their origin as ratios of sides of triangles has got lost in the distance.

Comment: Thanks! That was really helpful. By the way, are you familiar with the algorithm for finding the values of trigonometric functions that basically just summarizes the identities I refer to? Do you think that that algorithm really is necessary? I discussed it in a question here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3676830/why-do-we-use-this-complicated-algorithm-for-finding-values-of-trigonometric-fun

Comment: Never used it. I mistrust algorithms and mnemonics because then you are tempted not to learn the reasons and the true nature of a concept at the expense of a list of rules. Bad way to study mathematics. I learned at the start what a cosine and sine are, and whenever I need to remember one of the rules I flash up a little geometric diagram in my head. Cosine goes across and sine goes up and down. (Remember that "sine" was a mistranslation via Arabic of the Sanskrit word meaning "bowstring" and you are already there.)

Comment: You have no idea about how much troubled and confused I was due to that algorithm. While I find some  algorithms helpful, I hate all mnemonics like the one for remembering the signs for trigonometric functions in various quadrant **All** **S**chool **T**o **C**ollege. I wish there was a 'follow' option on this website. Thanks, again! PS : The 'algorithm' is useful for making a computer program though