# Complementary Trigonometric relationship for sine and cosine

Tags: functions, trigonometry, triangles, circles

To begin, let's start with the first quadrant in the unit circle:

[image]

It's easy to see why(due to complementary angles):

$$\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right) = \sin(\theta)$$
$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right) = \cos(\theta)$$

But what about Quadrant 2, 3 and 4, how do I visualise and prove these using the unit circle?

Q2:
$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta\right) = ???$$
$$\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta\right) = ???$$

Q3:

$$\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}-\theta\right) = ???$$
$$\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}-\theta\right) = ???$$

Q4:

$$\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}+\theta\right) = ???$$
$$\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}+\theta\right) = ???$$

Comment: Formatting suggestion:  Type `$\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2} - \theta\right)$` to obtain $\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2} - \theta\right)$.

Comment: "how do I visualize and prove these using the unit circle", rotate the circle , somethings stay same, somethings change sign, observe what stays same and what changes sign.

Comment: Related (duplicate?): ["How to remember a particular class of trig identities."](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/737212/409). See, in particular, [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/737353/409).