# Determining the input angle from the output of a trigonometric function

Tags: trigonometry

I am attempting to answer a set of questions where I need to find all possible values of $x$,
in the range $0 < x < 2\pi$, as a fraction of $\pi$, in a question such as:

$$\cos x = 1$$

For this one, and a few others, I could figure out how to reach the answer - normally either by 'special' triangles or using the unit circle. I reached this question, though, and could only come up with one part of the answer:

$$\sin x = \frac{1}{2}$$

I can see how to do this from a right angled triangle with sides $1$, $\sqrt{3}$, and $2$ - it's relatively straight forward to see that the sides with length $1$ and $2$ are the $O$ and $H$ part of $\sin \theta = \frac{O}{H}$. My problem here is how I'd figure out the other value of $x$ in the range $0 < x < 2\pi$ - I can't see how I can use a right angled triangle, and on the unit circle, I know that $sin \theta$ corresponds to the $y$ coordinate for points on the circle - but I can't see how I can use this to determine the angle.

Is there a way that makes sense to figure this out, other than just using a calculator?

Comment: yeah, e.g. $\sin(\pi-x)=x$. There are many similar identities that allow you to completely solve such equations

Comment: Equivalently, get comfortable with how a sine and cosine curve look (or learncompiound angle formulae!)

Comment: @FShrike Thanks! Bit of a face palm moment as I know I've seen that before... back to look over some problems in that area again I think. Appreciate the help!

Comment: No worries. These curves have very nice symmetry, it is good to be able to sketch them accurately *in your mind*!

Comment: @PJMasks: You may also find [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/737353/409) helpful.