# Why when we add or substract $\alpha$ to a odd multiple of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ inside $\sin/\cos$ we get cofunction?

Tags: trigonometry

Why when we add or substract $\alpha$ to a odd multiple of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ inside $\sin/\cos$ we get cofunction and when we do same thing with multiple of $\pi$ we get just same function but with sign depending on quarter? Where the transformation for $\frac{\pi}{2}$ comes from?

Comment: Do you know rotations and matrix representation?

Comment: Related (duplicate?): ["How to remember a particular class of trig identities"](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/737353/409)

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen if you mean rotations in quarters of trigonomrtyy fuctions, i do.

Comment: And matrix representations of linear maps ?

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen i dont think so

Comment: @peterwhy edited question

Comment: Do you know [angle addition formulas](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricAdditionFormulas.html)?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner im learning this now but thanks for good site with formulas. Also Blue TY for link. Ill try read both and understand this

Comment: There are two non-right angles in a right triangle. They are complementary angles, and what's adjacent to one is opposite to the other. So the cosine of an angle is the sine of its complement (indeed, this is where the name comes from).

Comment: Draw a picture.  It'll be absolutely obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Recall the sum/difference formulas:

$$\sin(x \pm y) = \sin x \cos y \pm \cos x \sin y$$
$$\cos(x \pm y) = \cos x \cos y \mp \sin x \sin y$$

Now, let $y = \frac{\pi}{2}n$ for some odd integer $n$.

$$\sin(x + \frac{\pi}{2}n) = \sin x \cos (\frac{\pi}{2}n) + \cos x \sin (\frac{\pi}{2}n)$$
$$\cos(x + \frac{\pi}{2}n) = \cos x \cos (\frac{\pi}{2}n) - \sin x \sin (\frac{\pi}{2}n)$$

But when $n$ is odd, $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}n) = 0$, so this simplifies to:

$$\sin(x + \frac{\pi}{2}n) = \cos x \sin (\frac{\pi}{2}n)$$
$$\cos(x + \frac{\pi}{2}n) = - \sin x \sin (\frac{\pi}{2}n)$$

Since $n$ is odd, there is an integer $k$ such that $n = 2k + 1$.  So:

$$\sin (\frac{\pi}{2}n) = \sin (\frac{\pi}{2}(2k + 1))$$
$$= \sin(\pi k + \frac{\pi}{2})$$
$$= \sin(\pi k)\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}) + \cos(\pi k)\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})$$
$$= 0 \times 0 + (-1)^k \times 1$$
$$= (-1)^k$$

Plugging into our previous set of equations gives:

$$\sin(x + \frac{\pi}{2}(2k + 1)) = (-1)^k\cos x$$
$$\cos(x + \frac{\pi}{2}(2k + 1)) = (-1)^{k+1}\sin x$$

Answer (score 2):

Even if OP does not know matrix representation of a rotation, it may be useful for some other readers.

Let $r(x)$ and $r(y)$ two rotations. In a direct orthonormal basis of the plane,$$r(x)=\begin{bmatrix}\cos x  & -\sin x \\ \sin x& \cos x\end{bmatrix}, r(y)=\begin{bmatrix}\cos y  & -\sin y \\ \sin y& \cos y\end{bmatrix}$$So, $$\begin{bmatrix}\cos x+y  & -\sin x+y \\ \sin x+y& \cos x+y\end{bmatrix}=r(x+y):=r(x)r(y)$$$$r(x-y):=r(x)r(y)^{-1}$$And we find the formulas provided by @Dan.