# Why do we take an acute angle remainder when finding trig ratios of allied angles?

Tags: trigonometry, angle

Say I have to find $\sin(\frac{19\pi}{3})$.

(Please note that I'm using the algorithmic method to solve this trigonometric function. This method can be found here:
[How to remember trigonometric ratios for allied angles?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/667582/how-to-remember-trigonometric-ratios-for-allied-angles))

This is
$$\sin(\frac{12\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{3})$$
Since 12 is even, $\sin$ remains as $\sin$.
The terminating ray also lies in the 1st quadrant, where $\sin$ is positive

So, this equates to
$$\sin(\frac\pi3)$$

My question was, why does it have to be an acute angle when solving this algorithmically?

Like, if I instead did
$$\sin(\frac{11\pi}2+\frac{5\pi}6)$$
$$\cos(\frac{5\pi}6)$$
$$\cos(\frac\pi2+ \frac\pi3)$$
$$-\sin(\frac\pi3)$$

This is clearly wrong. This was of course an out of the way example, but there are times when its convenient. So why can't we do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "allied angles" ? Angles equal mod $2 \pi$ ?

Comment: Angles whose sum or difference is either 0 or a multiple of $\frac\pi2$

Comment: So, like $\frac\pi3$ and $\frac{19\pi}3$ are allied angles

Comment: I see no equals signs.

Comment: $$\sin\left(\frac{11\pi}2+\frac{5\pi}6\right)=-\cos\frac{5\pi}6.$$

Comment: Like I said, I am not using the additive identity of $\sin$ and $\cos$, but rather the algorithm for solving it quickly. Its given here-https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/667582/how-to-remember-trigonometric-ratios-for-allied-angles

Comment: Although I am not sure to understand properly your question, I am tempted to give the following answer : in this way, you get the positive reference values of $\sin$ and $\cos$...